# SwiftUI how to update data in a View Model with data from another View Model

Tags: swift, swiftui, singleton, observableobject

I am trying to update `@Published` arrays in separate view models, one view model is a singleton whilst the other is not as there can be multiple instances.

- The purpose of the code below is to allow a user to save or unsave
  movie recommendations to their personal movie collection
  (`savedMovies`).
- The `MyMovies` class is a singleton, this is intentional as there is only one user.
- The `MovieShop` class is not a singleton as there can be multiple movie shops and therefore multiple instances.
- When a user presses "Save" on a movie name, the movie should be added to their saved movies (MyMovies class) and the movie must be shown as "Saved" in the Movie Recommendation list (MovieShop class).
- When the movie is removed from the users `savedMovie` array, in all movie shops (only one shown in the example code) the movie that was removed from the `savedMovie` array must have its `saved` state reset to `false` so so it can be saved again (by the user pressing "Save").

The implementation below works when pressing the save/unsave button for each movie in the movie recommendations view but not for the users saved movies view (as it removes the movie entirely).

**My question is this:**

I have been looking at the Apple Developer Docs in an attempt to understand the correct way to go about doing this when working within the SwiftUI framework.  So far I haven't had much luck finding an answer.  Is the proposed solution within the Apple Guidelines or is there another way in which i should go about solving this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Movie type
struct Movie: Hashable {
    let name: String
    var saved: Bool
}

@MainActor final class MyMovies: ObservableObject {
    @Published var savedMovies: [Movie] = [Movie(name: "Ice Age", saved: true)]
    
    static let shared = MyMovies()
    
    private init() {}
    // function to remove a movie from the users saved movies
    func unsaveMovie(_ movie: Movie) {
        savedMovies.removeAll(where: {$0.name == movie.name})
        // Need to also toggle saved state of unsaved/removed movie so
        // its state is set to "Save" in movie shop (not sure how)
    }
}

@MainActor class MovieShop: ObservableObject {
    @Published var recommendations: [Movie] = [
        Movie(name: "Ice Age", saved: true),
        Movie(name: "Star Wars", saved: false),
    ]
    // function to save or unsave a movie depending on if it is
    // already in the users saved movies array or not
    func toggleMovieSaved(_ movie: Movie) {
        let index = recommendations.firstIndex(where: {$0.name == movie.name})!
        recommendations[index].saved.toggle()
        
        // Check if user already has the movie saved
        let alreadySaved = MyMovies.shared.savedMovies.contains(where: {$0.name == movie.name})
        
        if alreadySaved {
            // Remove movie from users saved movies
            MyMovies.shared.savedMovies.removeAll(where: {$0.name == movie.name})
        } else {
            // Save/Add movie to users saved movies
            var newMovie = movie
            newMovie.saved = true
            MyMovies.shared.savedMovies.append(newMovie)
        }
    }
}
// I have combined the movie shop view and user saved movies view into one
// for demo purposes
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var myMovies = MyMovies.shared
    @StateObject private var movieShop = MovieShop()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("My Saved Movies")
                .font(.title)
            ForEach(myMovies.savedMovies, id: \.name) { movie in
                HStack {
                    Text(movie.name)
                    Button("Remove") {
                        myMovies.unsaveMovie(movie)
                    }
                }
            }
            Divider()
            Text("Movie Recommendations")
                .font(.title)
            ForEach(movieShop.recommendations, id: \.name) { movie in
                HStack {
                    Text(movie.name)
                    Button(movie.saved ? "Unsave" : "Save") {
                        movieShop.toggleMovieSaved(movie)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually there is just one object that loads/saves/stores all the different model struct arrays, e.g.

```
class ModelStore: ObservableObject {
    var savedMovies: [Movie]
    var recommendations: [Movie]
```

Since `Movie` is a struct you might have better luck using arrays of IDs instead for the saved and recommendations then lookup an allMovies array - see favouriteSmoothies in the [Fruta sample](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fruta_building_a_feature-rich_app_with_swiftui).

You might be able to solve your problem of multiple objects instead by using a View struct with a binding. In SwiftUI think of the View struct as the View model, and the view hierarchy transforms from complex model types, e.g. your `Movie` into simple value types (for easy previewing).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I looked at the Fruta sample and see what you mean by using IDs instead.  However, I don't understand what you mean by thinking of a View struct as the View model.  Would the binding take the singleton's `savedMovies` array and then you create a function within the View to check if a movie is already saved?  Also if I remove a movie from the `savedMovies`, how do I update each individual movie `recommendations` array to reflect the change, should that done through a function in a View as well?